# Internal error on the Amadeus POI API in production

Tags: internal-server-error, amadeus

Good morning, When I try to contact the Amadeus API to get points of interest, it gives me an internal error.

Sometimes it returns to me this :

```
 {
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": 38189,
            "title": "Internal error",
            "detail": "An internal error occurred, please contact your administrator",
            "status": 500
        }
    ]
}
```

Or an html code.

Comment: Hi Julien, can you provide the arguments that sent to the API please?

Comment: If you can share a snipped code with the SDK call, it could be great to review internally.

Comment: Hello, here is an example of request which is crashing for me :
latitude: 47.866844
longitude: 3.493748
radius: 20
It's also crashes for other arguments

Answer (score 0):

If you want an example of request with more details:

[image: The request]

Comment: Hi Julien, you are right, we have reported the incident today in order to solve it. We will inform about the progress.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).